# How to launch CommandLineRunner from Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, program-entry-point

I have a main Spring Boot application in the top-level package that I launch, with different controllers in the children packages:

i.e.

```
ca.example.batch.MainBatchApplication
ca.example.batch.job1.Job1Controller (/batch/startJob1)
ca.example.batch.job2.Job2Controller (/batch/startJob2)
```

I am able to start the Spring Batches by going to the URL: http://localhost:8080/batch/startJob1 or http://localhost:8080/batch/startJob2.

However, in another package I have:

```
ca.example.batch.job3.Job3Controller
ca.example.batch.job3.Job3Application
```

... which is not a Spring Batch, but a Spring CommandLineRunner. I want to know if there is a way to launch MainBatchApplication without starting that CommandLineRunner automatically, but run it through the controller, i.e. http://localhost:8080/batch/startJob3.

The controller code I am looking at is:

```
package ca.example.batch.job3;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Job3Controller {

    @RequestMapping("/batch/startJob3")
    public String handle() throws Exception {

        Job3Application app = new Job3Application();

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

        logger.info("app: " + app);

        String args = "";
        app.run(args);

        return "COMPLETE";
    }
}
```

Job3Application is:

```
package ca.example.batch.job3;

import static java.lang.System.exit;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import ca.example.batch.common.CommonLibraryReference;
import ca.example.batch.common.domain.WasHost;
import ca.example.batch.common.svc.WasHostService;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(CommonLibraryReference.class)
public class Job3Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Job3Application.class);

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public WasHostService wasHostService;

    public Job3Application() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Job3Application.class)
        .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
        .bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF)
        .run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Loading data...");

        logger.info("wasHostService: " + wasHostService);
        List<WasHost> hostList = wasHostService.findAll();
        if (!hostList.isEmpty()) {
            for (WasHost host : hostList) {
                logger.info("hostname: " + host.getHostname());
            }
        } else {
            logger.info("No hosts found in database. Aborting data collection.");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get in the log is:

```
""2018-07-07 12:56:09 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
""2018-07-07 12:56:09 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] INFO  c.e.b.job3.Job3Controller - app: ca.example.batch.job3.Job3Application@472d7ac
""2018-07-07 12:56:09 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] INFO  c.e.b.job3.Job3Application - Loading data...
""2018-07-07 12:56:09 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] INFO  c.e.b.job3.Job3Application - wasHostService: null
""2018-07-07 12:56:09 [http-nio-9191-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
"java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at ca.example.batch.job3.Job3Application.run(Job3Application.java:47)
    at ca.example.batch.job3.Job3Controller.handle(Job3Controller.java:21)
```

... when I launch the controller request.

If this isn't the right way, please advise.

Basically, what I am trying to do is launch a main() from within a controller but use the MainBatchApplication runtime to run it (if that makes sense?). When the program is done, it send the return code back to the controller and shows in the browser.

Thank you,
Joey

Comment: deleted answer as the question has changed. `Job3Application run(...)` only does some logging or terminates the application !? So I don't think this is very usefull.

Comment: I removed a lot of the code for simplicity. However, looking at the code I have, Job3Application should retrieve a list from the database and log them. This is not happening because « wasHostService » is null. If I run Job3Application by itself it works fine. It fails when requesting with controller...

Comment: guess you forgotten to add  `@Import(CommonLibraryReference.class)` in `MainBatchApplication` ?

Comment: No, it’s part of it. I added it to Job3Application to see if it would help, but it didn’t.

Comment: There’s something about the instantiation of “app” inside Job3Controller that doesn’t initialize the @Autowired WasHostService in Job3Application.

Comment: again: Job3Application run(...) only does some logging or terminates the application !? So you should not do `new Job3Application()` either! Just create a `component` where you do the imported stuff you need to do and use (constructor) injection to get that component in your controller and trigger the method to execute the job.

Comment: note that you should be able to autowire `Job3Application` in your controller...and you should see logging lines in your console *Loading data...* , *wasHostService:..*

Answer (score 1):

`ca.example.batch.MainBatchApplication` is the main appliction you start.
So it scans all Components in package `ca.example.batch`. That means it should detect `ca.example.batch.job3.Job3Application` so you should be able to `@Autowire`it in the `Job3Controller`

this should work:

```
@Controller
public class Job3Controller {
  private final Job3Application job3Application;      

  public Job3Controller (Job3Application job3Application){
     this.job3Application = job3Application;
  }

  @RequestMapping("/batch/startJob3")
  public String handle() throws Exception {
    String[] args = ...
    this.job3Application.run(args);
    return "COMPLETE";
  }

  ....
}
```

Comment: why not jsut created a shared service between the runner and controller so you don't have to mix the implementations?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe correct that would be a better approach (and I suggested this in comments)... but that doesn't answer the question 'How to launch CommandLineRunner from Spring Controller'

Comment: Dirk, with your code I get this on MainBatchApplication startup:

`Consider defining a bean of type 'ca.example.batch.job3.Job3Application' in your configuration.`

Comment: if you didn't exclude `Job3Application` in your `MainBatchApplication` it should be present. Every `@SpringBootApplication` is by itself an `@Configuration` so it's a bean... Can you show use MainBatchApplication?

Comment: Ah! I excluded the classes of type “CommandLineRunner” because I didn’t want it to start with MainBatchApplication, but only when Job3Controller is called. If I remove the exclude from MainBatchApplication, what should I do in Job3Application to prevent automatic run?

Comment: is't that obvious? remove commandlinerunner, rename run()-method and call it from your controller...

Comment: I started reading on CommandLineRunner and the puspose of it (which is run after application startup) was against what I was trying to accomplish. I did what you said and now I can trigger the code of the run() method (in Job3Application) from my controller. There is nothing obvious when you're a beginner. Thank you for your help. I will accept your answer.